# Solving an ODE using Picard's Iteration Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find the exact solution of the IVP

$y'=y^2$, $y(0)=1$

Starting with $y_0(x)=1$, apply Picard's method to calculate $y_1(x),y_2(x),y_3(x)$, and compare these results with the exact solution.

> Solving this IVP with separation of variables, I get that $y(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Now using Picard's method ($y_n(x)=y_0+\int_0^xf[t,y_{n-1}(t)]dt$), i get

\begin{align}
y_0(x) & =1 \\
y_1(x) & =1+x \\
y_2(x) & =1+x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{3} \\
y_3(x) & =1+x+x^2+x^3+\frac{2x^4}{3}+\frac{x^5}{3}+\frac{x^6}{9}+\frac{x^7}{63}
\end{align}

By now, I would have expected to see some pattern, but I don't really see anything, and continuing to iterate I don't think will get me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you to better understand what is going on:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

The two results are actually equivalent for $|x|<1$ since the Picard iteration is converging to a geometric series, which is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Yes, but the question doesn't say anything about restricting $x$ to $|x|<1$

Comment: Note that the Picard-Lindelöf theorem relies upon the Lipschitz condition being satisfied so that the Banach fixed point theorem is applicable. Far enough away from the origin x=0, these conditions no longer apply, hence you cannot expect the solution from Picard iteration to converge everywhere. If it does converge, it will only converge to the Taylor series of the solution, and the Taylor series obviously does not have to converge everywhere.

Comment: Note that $y'=y^2$ will no longer give a contraction for $|x|>1$, which is why the solution from Picard iteration diverges there. So again, your results are correct and self-consistent.